# Critical points of a nonnegative quadratic form on a subspace

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x)=x^tAx$ for some square symmetric matrix $A\in R^{n\times n}$, such that $Q(x)\geq0$ for each $x\in R^n$.  Let $S$ be an affine subspace of $R^n$.  How can I show that if $y$ is a critical point of $Q$ on $S$, then $y$ is a point of global minimum of $Q$ on $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you have a strictly convex function in the subspace.